# Change moodle authentication type

Tags: authentication, moodle

I imported a list of users and choose "no login" as authentication type. I didn't want to send out mails to the imported users yet. How can I now change "no login" to "manual accounts"?

Answer (score 2):

Did you import them using the bulk user upload?

If you did, then you can import them again and change the `auth` column to `manual` - this should update them.

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Upload_users#Updating_users_preview

Comment: Hi Russell, yes I imported them and already imported them again as you suggested. But isn't there another option?

Answer (score 1):

Another option for changing the authentication source for a large number of users in bulk is to perform an update query on the database.

Note however that in most circumstances the best option will be to follow Russell England's advice in his answer and perform the update utilising the bulk user upload method, though in some select cases the update query method may well be preferable, depending on the situation of course. Keep in mind also that it is much easier to end up with more trouble than you started with using this method, and you should always have a full backup before attempting it and never perform it on a production environment.

With that said, the update query that will perform the change from "no login" to "manual" authentication is as follows:

```
   UPDATE mdl_user SET mdl_user.auth = "manual"
   WHERE mdl_user.auth = "nologin";
```

It should be noted that this update query utilises the standard database prefix of "mdl_" so if your prefix is different do be sure to change it as necessary.

The where condition in the query restricts the change to only those users currently set to use the "no login" authentication method, lest there be other users using an alternative method (ie. other than manual or nologin) that it would not be desirable to change from their present authentication method.

Further where clauses may be added of course in order to further reduce chances of unintended consequences depending on your situation and the specific set of users you wish to target, but for the straightforward scenario of all current "nologin" users changed over to "manual" authentication, this will do the trick.

However, this method naturally will not trigger any email or any other actions and won't do anything regarding passwords if they have not yet been set or disseminated to users.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Hi MattG, this is an answer I was looking for, but now I can't test this anymore as I already fixed it by using the first answer.

Comment: oh, and nice answer with disclaimer and a little SQL tutorial.